# Problem with DOM can't detect the changing value in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

This supposed to work like this if i select = USA it will show the state (Washington, Texas and NEW york as a dropdown option it is working in this state but then I tried to show which state i selected in the div. suppose if i select texas then it will show texas but instead of showing texas it only showing Washington as the first value. So how should i solve this? I don't want to use JQUERY thanks.

```js
function random_function() {
  var name = document.getElementById("output").value;
  document.getElementById("district").innerHTML = name;
  var a = document.getElementById("input").value;
  if (a === "INDIA") {
    var arr = ["Maharashtra", "Delhi"];
  } else if (a === "USA") {
    var arr = ["Washington", "Texas", "New York"];
  }

  var string = "";

  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    string = string + "<option>" + arr[i] + "</option>";
  }
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = string;
  var name = document.getElementById("output").value;
  document.getElementById("district").innerHTML = name;
}
```

```html
<select id="input" onchange="random_function()">
  <option>select option</option>
  <option>INDIA</option>
  <option>USA</option>
</select>
<div>
  <select id="output">
    <option></option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <p id="district" onchange="random_function()"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you want to display the selected location of the select submenu `onclick`.

This is one option:

```
 function random_function() {
      var a = document.getElementById("input").value;
      var arr; // get your var arr out of your if else blocks...
      if (a === "INDIA") {
        arr = ["Maharashtra", "Delhi"];
      } 
      if (a === "USA") {
        arr = ["Washington", "Texas", "New York"];
      }
      // clear your array if user selects "select option"
      if (a === "select option") {
         arr = [];
      }
    
      var string = "";
    
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        string = string + "<option>" + arr[i] + "</option>";
      }
      
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = string;
      
      // clear your displayed result when the state changes...
      var district = document.getElementById("district");
      district.innerHTML = "";
    }
    
    // when user clicks city in submenu, display it
    function display() {
      var district = document.getElementById("district");
      var value = document.getElementById("output").value;
      district.innerHTML = value;
     
    }
```

This is the [jsbin test](https://jsbin.com/zidahovoqe/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the value of your `#district` when the value of the second, as well as the first, dropdown menu changes. I would write another function for this:

```js
function random_function() {
  var name = document.getElementById("output").value;
  var a = document.getElementById("input").value;
  if (a === "INDIA") {
    var arr = ["Maharashtra", "Delhi"];
  } else if (a === "USA") {
    var arr = ["Washington", "Texas", "New York"];
  } else {
    var arr = [];
  }

  var string = "";

  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    string = string + "<option>" + arr[i] + "</option>";
  }
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = string;
  showDistrict();
}

function showDistrict() {
  var district_name = document.getElementById("output").value;
  document.getElementById("district").innerHTML = district_name;
}
```

```html
<select id="input" onchange="random_function()">
  <option>select option</option>
  <option>INDIA</option>
  <option>USA</option>
</select>
<div>
  <select id="output" onchange="showDistrict()">
    <option></option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <p id="district" onchange="random_function()"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: what happens if I select "select option" by mistake...?

Comment: this code has several bugs, please review your results. You are not clearing your div when the state changes.

Comment: You mean the district div? It is changing.

Comment: When the state of the main section changes. See my answer below.

Comment: You are welcome but my code isn't perfect or better. It is just tested. I have downvoted your answer because you had not tested your code and have provided a solution that had at least 2 bugs in it, yes.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add value to option tag.

```
<option value="India">India</option>
```

Comment: Hello, Dhruv option value isn't the concern here. This is working fine. My problem is with the output division. Thanks